# Sea escrito un arbol no equilibrado usando document.write()

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

Estoy aprendiendo a programar con objetos en *JavaScript* y tengo un error que no e encontrado solución e echo un método que que devuelve una información y dentro de esa información tengo etiquetas *html* y luego muestro la información con un `document.write` y los objetos y se muestra lo que esta escrito en las **``` `` ```** , pero no las variables que pongo dentro de las etiquetas el código trata de hacer un móvil con algunas funciones, estaba siguiendo el tutorial al pie de la letra pero al pibe del video no le pasaba nada y a mi si y me pasa mucho.

Aquí esta el código:

```
class Celular {
    constructor(color,peso,rdp,rdc,ram) {
        this.color = color;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.resolucionDePantalla = rdp;
        this.resolucionDeCamara = rdc;
        this.memoriaRam = ram;
        this.encendido = false;
    }
    presionarBotonEncendido() {
        if (this.encendido == false) {
            alert("celular prendido");
            this.encendido = true;
        }else {
            alert("el celular esta apagado")
            this.encendido = false;
        }
    }

    reiniciar() {
        if (this.encendido == true) {
            alert("reiniciando celular")
        }else {
            alert("el celular esta apagado")
        }
    }

    tomarFoto() {
        alert(`foto tomada en una resolucion de: 
            ${this.resolucionDeCamara}`)
    }

    grabarVideo() {
        alert(`grabando video en ${this.resolucionDeCamara}`)
    }

    mobileInfo() {
        return `
        color: <b>${this.color}</b></br>
        peso: <b>${this.peso}</b></br>
        tamaño: <b>${this.tamaño}</b></br>
        Resolucion de camara: <b>${this.resolucionDeCamara}</b></br>
        Resolucion de video: <b>${this.resolucionDeVideo}</b></br>
        Memoria RAM: <b>${this.memoriaRam}</b></br>
        `;
    }
}

celular1 = new Celular("rojo","150","5'","full hd","2GB");
celular2 = new Celular("verde","150","5,4'","Ultra 4k","4GB");
celular3 = new Celular("blanco","15046","5.9","full hd","3GB");


/*celular1.presionarBotonEncendido();
celular1.tomarFoto();
celular1.grabarVideo();
celular1.reiniciar();
celular1.presionarBotonEncendido();*/

document.write(`${celular1.mobileInfo} <br>${celular2.mobileInfo} <br>
${celular3.mobileInfo} <br> `);
`

y aqui el html que no tiene mucho pero tiene un link de un css que era solo para pruebas al igual que la fuente

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="cofla.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mochiy+Pop+P+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body id="body">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia esto:

```javascript
document.write(`${celular1.mobileInfo} <br>${celular2.mobileInfo} <br>
${celular3.mobileInfo} <br> `);
```

Por esto:

```javascript
document.write(`${celular1.mobileInfo()} <br>${celular2.mobileInfo()} <br>
${celular3.mobileInfo()} <br> `);
```

Y obtendrás esto:

```js
class Celular {
  constructor(color, peso, rdp, rdc, ram) {
    this.color = color;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.resolucionDePantalla = rdp;
    this.resolucionDeCamara = rdc;
    this.memoriaRam = ram;
    this.encendido = false;
  }
  presionarBotonEncendido() {
    if (this.encendido == false) {
      alert("celular prendido");
      this.encendido = true;
    } else {
      alert("el celular esta apagado")
      this.encendido = false;
    }
  }

  reiniciar() {
    if (this.encendido == true) {
      alert("reiniciando celular")
    } else {
      alert("el celular esta apagado")
    }
  }

  tomarFoto() {
    alert(`foto tomada en una resolucion de: 
            ${this.resolucionDeCamara}`)
  }

  grabarVideo() {
    alert(`grabando video en ${this.resolucionDeCamara}`)
  }

  mobileInfo() {
    return `
        color: <b>${this.color}</b></br>
        peso: <b>${this.peso}</b></br>
        tamaño: <b>${this.tamaño}</b></br>
        Resolucion de camara: <b>${this.resolucionDeCamara}</b></br>
        Resolucion de video: <b>${this.resolucionDeVideo}</b></br>
        Memoria RAM: <b>${this.memoriaRam}</b></br>
        `;
  }
}

celular1 = new Celular("rojo", "150", "5'", "full hd", "2GB");
celular2 = new Celular("verde", "150", "5,4'", "Ultra 4k", "4GB");
celular3 = new Celular("blanco", "15046", "5.9", "full hd", "3GB");


/*celular1.presionarBotonEncendido();
celular1.tomarFoto();
celular1.grabarVideo();
celular1.reiniciar();
celular1.presionarBotonEncendido();*/

document.write(`${celular1.mobileInfo()} <br>${celular2.mobileInfo()} <br>
${celular3.mobileInfo()} <br> `);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="cofla.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mochiy+Pop+P+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body id="body">
  </body>

</html>
```

**Explicación:**

Estabas llamando mal a la funcion `mobileinfo`, pues te faltaban los paréntesis finales `()`.